# Solving a nonlinear autonomous system using polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, nonlinear-system

I have the nonlinear system:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fx'=-y-x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\
y'=x-y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

which I solve by polar coordinates transformation. $x=r\cos\phi \ y=r\sin\phi$ and $x'=dr\cos\phi-r\sin\phi$ and $y'=dr\sin\phi+r\cos\phi$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fdr\cos\phi-r\sin\phi=-r\sin\phi-r\cos\phi\sqrt{r^2\cos^2\phi+r^2\sin^2\phi}\\
dr\sin\phi+r\cos\phi=r\cos\phi-r\sin\phi\sqrt{r^2\cos^2\phi+r^2\sin^2\phi}\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Clearly, many terms cancel out and we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fdr=-r^2\\
dr=-r^2\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Then, integrating both sides with respect to $r$ we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fr=-\frac{1}{3}r^3+c\\
r=-\frac{1}{3}r^3+c
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Since $r=\frac{x}{\cos\phi} and r=\frac{y}{\sin\phi}$ we get

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fx=-\frac{x^3}{\cos^2\phi}+c\cos\phi\\
y=-\frac{y^3}{\sin^3\phi}+c\sin\phi
\end{array}
\end{equation}

The summing up the two equations, and isolating for y, I get a very scary result:

y≈0.26457 sin^4(ϕ) cos(ϕ) (sqrt((27 c csc^9(ϕ) sec^2(ϕ) + 27 c csc^8(ϕ) sec^3(ϕ) - 27 x^3 csc^9(ϕ) sec^5(ϕ) - 27 x csc^9(ϕ) sec^3(ϕ))^2 + 108 csc^15(ϕ) sec^6(ϕ)) + 27 c csc^9(ϕ) sec^2(ϕ) + 27 c csc^8(ϕ) sec^3(ϕ) - 27 x^3 csc^9(ϕ) sec^5(ϕ) - 27 x csc^9(ϕ) sec^3(ϕ))^(1/3) - (1.2599 csc(ϕ) sec(ϕ))/(sqrt((27 c csc^9(ϕ) sec^2(ϕ) + 27 c csc^8(ϕ) sec^3(ϕ) - 27 x^3 csc^9(ϕ) sec^5(ϕ) - 27 x csc^9(ϕ) sec^3(ϕ))^2 + 108 csc^15(ϕ) sec^6(ϕ)) + 27 c csc^9(ϕ) sec^2(ϕ) + 27 c csc^8(ϕ) sec^3(ϕ) - 27 x^3 csc^9(ϕ) sec^5(ϕ) - 27 x csc^9(ϕ) sec^3(ϕ))^(1/3) and csc(ϕ) sec(ϕ)!=0

What went wrong here?

Thanks

**UPDATE**, with Jean Maries correction we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fx=\frac{\cos\phi}{\phi+c}\\
y=\frac{\sin\phi}{\phi+c}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Summing up and solving for y:

\begin{equation}
y=\frac{\cos\phi}{\phi+c}+\frac{\sin\phi}{\phi+c}-x
\end{equation}

which plotted , with an arbitrary value of $c$ is:

[image: Plot]

Comment: Your integration is wrong, $r'=-r^2$ gives $r(t)^{-1}=t+c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$dr=-r^2$ cannot be integrated as you do. You need to write it under the form

$$- \dfrac{dr}{r^2}=1$$

giving :

$$\dfrac{1}{r}=\varphi+c$$

($c$ arbitrary constant), otherwise said:

$$r=\frac{1}{\varphi+c}$$

Comment: Indeed, I was a little bit tired...Thanks for this reminder.